# Angular 2 Default route logic not working when app initiates

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get a test app to work based on the tutorial for Angular 2, but I'm running into a problem.

When I initially start the app, the default 'redirectTo' route's logic doesn't work until I go into a different component and back into the original one. In the case of the plunker here, clicking on any of the dashboard buttons do nothing until I switch into the "Heroes" component and back into the original Dashboard.

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KzWttn3ZlyMh0WW0JAum?p=preview

app.routes.ts:

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

export const AppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard'
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
    }
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(AppRoutes)
]
```

Comment: try adding terminal: true, this tells the redirect that 'dashboard' is as far as the redirect is going to go

Comment: The Plunker doesn't work and doesn't contain the `RouterConfig` shown above. Try https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html as template.

Comment: @JarodMoser Unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried reworking the plunker to the best of my ability here: https://plnkr.co/edit/P4iZRCASGSphGS3taANM

Comment: I suggest you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Answer (score 0):

try to add `terminal: true`

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    terminal: true
},
```